# row y col de boostrap en react (jsx)

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap

estoy utilizando boostrap en react y use las cards de boostrap usando informacion de props de otro componente. quiero que queden una al lado del la otra pero cuando uso row. col, lenght, etc de boostrap me quedan cinco cards iguales una al lado de la otra, y abajo otras cinco iguales. lo que yo necesito es que queden cinco por fila una al lado de la otra y obviamente, de distintos productos. este es codigo:

```
    import './Item.css';

    // import Button from 'react-bootstrap/Button';
    import Card from 'react-bootstrap/Card';
    import Col from 'react-bootstrap/Col';
    ItemCount from '../itemCount/ItemCount';
    import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

    const Item = (props) =>{

    const {title,price,stock,id,image} = props.data

       return (
      <Row xs={5} md={3} className="g-1">
      {Array.from({ length: 4 }).map((_, idx) => (
    <Col>
      <Card>
        <Card.Img variant="top" src="holder.js/100px160" />
        <Card.Body>
          <Card.Title>Card title</Card.Title>
          <Card.Text>
            This is a longer card with supporting text below as a                                     
               natural
               lead-in to additional content. This content is a little 
               bit
               longer.
             </Card.Text>
            </Card.Body>
           </Card>
           </Col>
        ))}
       </Row>

     );

    }

    export default Item
```

Comment: En el codigo que muestras no se ve que estes usando `row` ni `col`

Comment: @David081 ahi lo edite! perdon!

Comment: Todo lo que estas haciendo lo estas enviando a una solo _row_ esa es la razón, agrega algo de logica como llevar un contador y cuando te de 5 crea otra row